# Qt: QUrl::fromUserInput intepretes FTP Url wrong

Tags: qt, networking, qurl

I have some issue in passing a FTP string into QUrl:

```
std::cout << QUrl::fromUserInput("ftp://user@host.com:password@ftphost:21/path/file.ext").toString().toStdString().c_str() << std::endl;
```

Is always resulting in

```
http://ftp//user@host.com:password@ftphost:21/path/file.ext
```

which is obviously wrong. What's the problem with the above FTP Url? Or is that a known issue within Qt4?

I am working on Linux, using Qt 4.8.1.

Even following code

```
if(QUrl("ftp://user@host.com:password@ftphost:21/path/file.ext").isValid())
    std::cout << "is valid" << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "is not valid" << std::endl;
```

Is resulting in "is not valid"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need manually replace `@` in username with `%40`. That's what [QUrl](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qurl.html) does internally if [QUrl::setUserName()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qurl.html#setUserName) is called with `user@domain.tld`.

Comment: Thanks Oleg for the hint! I was able to fix the issue with your help, however, using Qt4, authentication will fail because of the %40. I am just doing a hack to get that resolved: `finalUrl.setUserName(QUrl::fromEncoded(finalUrl.userName().toLatin1()).toString());` With passing `%40` to QUrl and this small correction, everything works fine. Even on Qt4. Thanks again